# How to push multiple values into a array?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to do a foreach that sum some values by vendors from a SQL and push them into a array, thos vendors and values gonna be showing in some charts later, i'm using php + Laravel

Here's my foreach loop

```
  foreach ($array2 as $row) {
      $vendedor = $row->FUNC_NOME;
      if ($vendedor <> $row->FUNC_NOME) {
        $vendedor = $row->FUNC_NOME;
      }else{
        $saldo_campanha = ceil(procedure($row->RAD_CODIGO, $row->VALORENTRADA)) - ceil(procedure($row->RAD_CODIGO, $row->VALORSAIDA));
        $entrada = $entrada + ceil(procedure($row->RAD_CODIGO, $row->VALORENTRADA));
        $saida = $saida + procedure($row->RAD_CODIGO, $row->VALORSAIDA);
      }
  }

  array_push($arr, [
    "SALDO"        => ceil($saldo_campanha),
    "VALORENTRADA" => $entrada,
    "VALORSAIDA"   => $saida,
    "FUNCIONARIO"  => $vendedor
  ]);
```

The procedure just make some percentage calulations on the values.

Comment: Does `array_merge()` instead of `array_push()` work? If `$arr` is already an array, and you want to add keys `'SALDO'`, `'VALORENTRADA'`, then it should work here.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment. $arr is an empty array that's gonna be returned from the function. That foreach should calculate the values for each employee and push to that array with the employee's name. Another thing i forgot to specify, my SQL has an Union, so it come with a lot of values

Comment: No problem! So if you use `array_push($arr, ["SALDO" => 1, "VALORENTRADA" => 2, "VALORSAIDA" => 3, "FUNCIONARIO" => 3])`, you end up with `[["SALDO" => 1, "VALORENTRADA" => 2, "VALORSAIDA" => 3, "FUNCIONARIO" => 3]]` (A nested array). Compare with `array_merge()`: `["SALDO" => 1, "VALORENTRADA" => 2, "VALORSAIDA" => 3, "FUNCIONARIO" => 3]`, a single array with those 4 keys. The SQL union and what not seems irrelevant, but from that info, pick the method that works for your use-case  `array_push` is what you want if you're iterating, `array_merge` will overwrite on each call

Comment: Right, i'm gonna test it. thanks for the reply.

Comment: Hey, a did some tests, but it's still not quite working, it's not separating by employee and adding just the last marked employy to the array

Comment: You need to do the `array_push` **inside** of the loop...

Comment: hey, sorrey for the delay, It works, thank you very much

Comment: Excellent! Feel free to post a self-answer below with the updated details to properly close of this question. Cheers!